# Is there a way to stream data received from an http endpoint directly into kafka using http4s?

Tags: scalaz-stream, http4s

http4s uses scalaz streams and there is scalaz streams implementation for kafka. Can we directly stream data received at an http endpoint into kafka like, http endpoint being the source and kafka being sink.

Like,

```
Source(HttpStream).map(...).to(Sink(kafka)
```